# Is gauge invariance essential to a theory be renormalizable?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, gauge-theory, renormalization, gauge-invariance

Let's consider a model of New Physics in which all operator have dimension smaller than four, but which breaks explicitly $SU(2)_L$ gauge symmetry.

- Is this model necessarily renormalizable?

Based on that,

- What is the exact relation between renormalizability and gauge invariance?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/110402/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/128053/2451 and links therein.